# sql: why is there a need for subqueries in this instance where it's one table?

Tags: sql

http://books.google.com/books?id=IkBxyCMqwI8C&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=%22As+I+mentioned+earlier,+one+of+the+primary+reasons+to+use+table%22&source=bl&ots=99Jq7v1MVv&sig=XbjdrjSwKntQJ5nVifHJr1lYxjc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6OIRVNDVFaKsjAKmnoHwBg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22As%20I%20mentioned%20earlier%2C%20one%20of%20the%20primary%20reasons%20to%20use%20table%22&f=false

search for "As I mentioned earlier, one of the primary reasons to use table alias"

Question:  How come this guy is using sub queries on the "same" table (one table)?  I understand it's to avoid ambiguity, but can't the query be this instead:

```
Select cust_id, cust_name, cust_contact
From customers
Where cust_contact ='Jim Jones';
```

I assume customer contact = a customer of jim jones who also happens to work where jim jones work.

This morning, I was trying to look for the source code.  But it doesn't appear to be available.

The book's code is

```
Select cust_id, cust_name, cust_contact
From customers
Where cust_name = (select cust_name  from customers where cust_contact = 'jim jones');
```

Comment: You're right.  There really doesn't appear to be a reason for a subquery there.

Comment: That would be true if it was known what `cust_name` was associated with `cust_contact = 'jim jones'`

Comment: Those are not the same....look closely at the example in the book...

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the subquery is that there are multiple records with the same `'cust_name'` as `jim jones`.  The example in the book uses `"cust_name"` for the *company*, not the *individual*.

Maybe a better example is:

```
SELECT * from Cars
WHERE make = (SELECT make FROM Cars where Model = "Explorer")
```

That will select all "Fords" without explicitly having "Ford" in the query.

Comment: +1 clear example! the example in the book can be confusing to beginners.

Answer (score 1):

The result can be different. If there are two customers named 'john doe', and only one of them has a contact named 'jim jones', then then your query will only return that one customer, while the query from the book will return all customers with the same name.

I doubt whether that is the result you would want, but there certainly is a difference.

If `cust_name` is a unique field, the result will be the same both both queries, and in that case the subselect adds unnecessary complexity.

{edit} I didn't read the book yet, but now I see that is actually also what it shows as example output, so this behaviour is intended. It is put in the book to point out this difference, and is actually working towards the next example with the self-join, with which you can achieve a similar result. Either way is different from your simpler query, which would return only the exact customer that has 'jim jones' for a contact,.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, those queries are not the same.....but the book have an error....I suggested to use `IN` instead of `=` in case there is more then one with Jim Jones as contact...or you will get :

`Subquery returns more than 1 row: Select cust_id, cust_name, cust_contact From customers Where cust_name = (select cust_name from customers where cust_contact = 'jim jones')`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a4ef0/2)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE customers
    (`cust_id` int, `cust_name` varchar(7), `cust_contact` varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO customers
    (`cust_id`, `cust_name`, `cust_contact`)
VALUES
    (10003, 'Fun4All', 'Jim Jones'),
    (10004, 'Fun4All', 'Denise'),
    (10005, 'Fun4you', 'Jim Jones'),
    (10006, 'Fun4you', 'Claude'),
    (10007, 'Fun4me', 'Pierre')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
Select cust_id, cust_name, cust_contact
From customers
Where cust_contact ='Jim Jones'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a4ef0/2/0)**:

```
| CUST_ID | CUST_NAME | CUST_CONTACT |
|---------|-----------|--------------|
|   10003 |   Fun4All |    Jim Jones |
|   10005 |   Fun4you |    Jim Jones |
```

**Query 2**:

```
Select cust_id, cust_name, cust_contact
From customers
Where cust_name in 
       (select cust_name from customers where cust_contact = 'jim jones')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a4ef0/2/1)**:

```
| CUST_ID | CUST_NAME | CUST_CONTACT |
|---------|-----------|--------------|
|   10003 |   Fun4All |    Jim Jones |
|   10004 |   Fun4All |       Denise |
|   10005 |   Fun4you |    Jim Jones |
|   10006 |   Fun4you |       Claude |
```